# wait for process to complete before going on to next step vbs

Tags: vbscript, scripting, login-automation

This is my vbs code

```
Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj.Exec "C:\Program Files\putty.exe -load " + "111.22.33.44"
WScript.Sleep 5000
obj.SendKeys "abc"
obj.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 3000
obj.SendKeys "abc123"
obj.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 3000
```

This code is functioning properly, however if i try it on a different computer sometimes it does not work. As soon as putty loads the username and password is entered without the terminal asking for it. Is there an alternative way like the following logic

```
waitforstring = uname :
if waitforstring = true
obj.sendKey "abc"
```

any help on this is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Use `obj.Run "C:\Program Files\putty.exe -load 111.22.33.44", ,True` to force blocking instead of using `.Exec`.

Comment: Since you're loading a session anyway: just save the username with the session, use public key authentication instead of password authentication, and stop using `SendKeys` altogether.